# Uploading a posted file to FTP corrupts it in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, upload, ftpwebrequest

Successful image HTTP upload. I'm doing the preview with JavaScript before loading.

The picture convert black when the image is loaded.
Could it be a problem with the `StreamReader`?

Can you see, what am I missing? Thanks..

## asp.net

```xml
<input id="fileupload2" type="file" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
```

## Codebehind

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileupload2.PostedFile.FileName);
using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(fileupload2.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());                
    fileStream.Close();
}

try
{
    if (fileupload2.PostedFile.ContentLength < 5120000)
    {
        //Create FTP Request.
        FtpWebRequest request =
            (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + fileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        //Enter FTP Server credentials.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS");
        request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
        request.EnableSsl = false;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //   lblMessage.Text += fileName + " uploaded.<br />";
        response.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
            this, this.GetType(), "Dikkat",
            "alert('Dosya 5 MB'dan küçük olmalıdır.')", true);
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());
> ```

You try to interpret a binary file as an UTF-8 text. That just cannot work.

Moreover your implementation is quite inefficient as you unnecessarily copy a whole file into the memory.

---

This is a simple and efficient solution:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + fileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS");

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    fileupload2.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
}
```

---

No other code is needed:

- `UsePassive = true`, `UseBinary = true` and `EnableSsl = false` are defaults.
- `ContentLength` is not used in `FtpWebRequest`.
- `FtpWebRequest.GetResponse` call is not needed for uploads.
- `ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit` has nothing to do with number of bytes.

Comment: which line I need to write

Comment: Remove whole `using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(fileupload2.PostedFile.InputStream)) { ... }` block and replace the `requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);` with `fileupload2.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(requestStream);`.

Comment: You should remove the `filebytes` variable. And remove the `request.ContentLength = ...` too, it's not used anyway.

Comment: I have added more information to my answer, including a complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is due to `StreamReader` also. StreamReader is specifically for text, not just any `byte[]`.

Instead, I would simply use `FileUpload.FileBytes` to retrieve the data versus `FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream`. Or you could use `Stream.Read()` which is for streams of more generic data.